# How to ignore interceptors in axios as a parameter?

Tags: javascript

I have axios interceptors, is it possible to ignore interceptors for one request by invoke the axios method?

something like: `axios.post('/path/foo', null, { ignoreInterceptors: true } })`

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: See the last example in this section of the docs for the appropriate solution https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors. You create a brand new excuse object that has no interceptors and use that to make an unintercepted request. This seems preferable to mutating the global axios object by removing interceptors that other requests depend on

Comment: and how to ignore one of interceptors?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Instead of:

```
axios.post('/path/foo')
```

you do:

```
const uninterceptedAxiosInstance = axios.create();
uninterceptedAxiosInstance.post('/path/foo')
```

and nothing will intercept that request.

Answer (score 4):

TO skip interceptor configuration , in request config you should add, `validateStatus` to  `null` or `false`

```
   axios.request({
url: 'https://api.example.com',
method: 'get',
validateStatus:null
})
```

Comment: the only way to solve it, all other methods failed to me.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When I need some more fine-grained behavior, I use the `config` object to pass a parameter with an `if` inside the interceptor.

```
axios.post(
    url,
    body,
    {
        ignoreGlobalCatch: true,
    },
);
```

```
...
async function (error) {
    if (!error.config.ignoreGlobalCatch) {
        //global catch (e.g: Show toast message)
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

In the interceptor request you can check for an overwrite like so:

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const accessToken = getAuthToken();

    config.headers!["Authorization"] =
      config.headers && config.headers["Authorization"] !== undefined
        ? config.headers["Authorization"]
        : accessToken;
    config.headers!["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    config.headers!["Accept"] = "application/json";

    return config;
  },
  (error) => Promise.reject(error)
);
```

so if you want to overwrite the authorization token in a single request but still you want to use the same axios instance you can make a request like that:

```
axiosInstance.get(`/endpoint`, {
  headers: { Authorization: "" },
})
```